# New maven project fails to compile: "App.java:[1,8] <identifier> expected"

Tags: java, maven, archetypes, generate

My steps:

```
$ mkdir maven-test
$ cd maven-test
$ mvn archetype:generate
```

I then entered

- `1313` for the quickstart archetype.
- `8` for quickstart archetype version 1.4.
- `info.cameronhudson.18655` for the groupId
- `lab1` for the artifactId
- `1.0` for the snapshot version
- `public-recommendation-service` for the package name
- `Y` for confirmation

I then entered the new project and tried to install it.

```
$ cd lab1
$ mvn clean install
```

This produced the following compilation errors.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/cameronhudson/Repositories/CMU/18-655_Lab_1_Public_Recommendation_Service/lab1/src/main/java/public-recommendation-service/App.java:[1,8] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] /Users/cameronhudson/Repositories/CMU/18-655_Lab_1_Public_Recommendation_Service/lab1/src/main/java/public-recommendation-service/App.java:[1,15] class, interface, or enum expected
[INFO] 2 errors
```

`App.java` contains (by default):

```
package public-recommendation-service;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

My java version:

```
$ java --version
java 11.0.2 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+7-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package names must be valid Java identifiers.  That means that your package name is invalid for 2 reasons.

There are hyphens, which are not allowed in an identifier.  The parser in the compiler thinks that the identifier is the portion of your package name before the first hyphen, which is `public`.  That is a keyword and not allowed as an identifier.

Try a different package name such as `public_recommendation_service` or `pubrecservice`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm surprised that the CLI accepted the invalid package name.